# консультации / рекоменднации по asset store

Tags: unity3d

*Есть:* деньги и серьёзные намерения.
*Нужно:* хорошая консультация по ассетам на asset store. То есть, рекомендация, что купить для нашего случая.
Существует ли некий аналог продавцов/консультантов в asset store? Или хорошие обзорщики ассетов, делающие обзоры платных ассетов на регулярной основе?

Comment: Может лучше нанять работника, типа левелдизанер и тд, раз не знаете что надо.    Какого типа ассеты?

Comment: Я знаю, что надо, но есть различные варианты в каждой категории. Сравнивать их не пробуя - то ещё удовольствие. Это вычитывание большого куска коментариев к ассету, и прочая прочая. Даже пробуя - тоже сомнительное удовольствие. Хотелось бы воспользоваться чьим то опытом, чтобы избежать полноценного длительного процесса отбора асетов.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не соответсвует [тематике сайта](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Возможно, я плохо понимаю тонкости тематики. Наверно, вопрос слишком обобщенный: как выбирать ассеты на asset store? Извините, если что напутал. Не буду против, если вопрос закроют.